# Intuition for why gluing two $\operatorname{Spec} k[\varepsilon]$ gives $\operatorname{Spec} k[\varepsilon_1, \varepsilon_2]$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, soft-question, schemes, singularity

Sorry for the terse title; the 150-character limit really gets in the way when you have to include "\varepsilon" in the title several times.

Write $k[\varepsilon]$ for the dual numbers, i.e. $k[x]/(x^2)$.

If we glue two copies of $\operatorname{Spec} k[\varepsilon]$ along their closed points, we get $\operatorname{Spec} k[\varepsilon_1, \varepsilon_2]$.

In geometric terms, if we take two points, each with "one dimension's worth of tangent information" attached, and glue the points together, we get a point with "two dimensions' worth of tangent information attached."  This is related to the fact that tangent spaces always really are vector spaces, even in cases where the tangent *cone* is not.

In contrast, if we glue, say, two copies of $\operatorname{Spec} k[x]$ together at one of their points we'd get $\operatorname{Spec} k[x,y]/(xy)$, a space where you can move away from the glue point in two *distinct* directions.

So if you glue two lines together you somehow preserve the fact that some directions are along the lines and others aren't, whereas if you glue two "infinitesimal lines" together you can no longer see what direction the infinitesimal lines had pointed in from the resulting space alone.

By "directions" here I mean that the inclusion of e.g. $\operatorname{Spec} k[x] \hookrightarrow \operatorname{Spec} k[x,y]/(xy)$ determines a tangent vector in $T_{(0,0)} \operatorname{Spec} k[x,y]/(xy)$.

I can calculate that all these things are true, but I've never really been able to internalize the idea.  Does anyone have a nice way of thinking about this?

Comment: It seems to me that this is a phenomenon that even happens in differential geometry. Really, unless you make an explicit identification of $T_0\mathbb{R}^2$ with $\mathbb{R}^2$ there is no real labeling of the axes--this 'directionality' of tangent vectors in terms of the original space is somewhat choice dependent no? The space of tangent vectors doesn't contain knowledge about actual directions on the original space, but what it does contain is 'independence of directions'.  I can say more if this resonates at all with you.

Comment: "Really, unless you make an explicit identification of $T_{(0,0)} \mathbb{R}^2$ with $\mathbb{R}^2$ there is no real labeling of the axes"

Well, curves through $(0,0)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ determine tangent vectors in $T_{(0,0)} \mathbb{R}^2$.  That doesn't require making any extra identifications.

Comment: Like what I'm saying to you is that $T_0\mathbb{R}^2$ is $\mathbb{R}^2$ just like $\mathcal{O}_{X,0}/\mathfrak{m}_0^2\cong k[\varepsilon_1,\varepsilon_2]$ (where $X$ is the intersecting lines). Once you choose an identification of $\mathbb{R}^2$ with $T_0\mathbb{R}^2$ you can make sense of specific directions, but not before that.

Comment: How are you defining $T_{(0,0)} \mathbb{R}^2$ in such a way that it doesn't come preequipped from the outset with a map taking curves through $(0,0)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ to vectors in $T_{(0,0)} \mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: Let $V$ be a two-dimensional vector space. Then, $V$ does not inherently have directions. But, an identification $V\cong T_0\mathbb{R}^2$ allows one to give a mapping from curves through $0$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $V$ giving $V$ a sense of direction. I'm saying that $\mathrm{Spec}(k[\varepsilon_1,\varepsilon_2])$ is like $V$ and you can give it 'explicit directions' by choosing an identification of $k[\varepsilon_1,\varepsilon_2]$ with $\mathcal{O}_{X,0}/\mathfrak{m}_0^2$. Does that clarify at all what I'm trying to communicate? If not, I'll give some thought of how to say it more cogently.

Comment: @AlexYoucis I agree with that but I think the situation at hand is different.  $\operatorname{Spec} k[x,y]/(xy)$ inherently has two privileged directions; $\operatorname{Spec} k[\varepsilon_1, \varepsilon_2]$ does not.  But both are formed by gluing "lines" at a point; it's just that one is an actual line and the other is an "infinitesimal line."

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98271/discussion-between-daniel-mclaury-and-alex-youcis).

Comment: Perhaps the point is that the 'privileged directions' that you're speaking of are not visible just from first order data, and the analogy of $\operatorname{Spec} k[\varepsilon]$ with a line only works up to 'first order' (in some sense). After all, the tangent space at the node is 2-dimensional. The privileged directions correspond to the two (vector spaces of) tangent vectors which can be lifted to higher order deformations (in fact induced from an *algebraic* curve mapping to the node).

Comment: @loch I know that from looking at the rings but it doesn't seem "intuitive" to me.  Maybe the problem is that in the smooth case people conflate the tangent space and tangent cone, giving an invalid impression of what a tangent space really is.

Comment: Maybe I'm just rusty, but when I glue together two copies of $\text{Spec } k[\varepsilon]/\varepsilon^2$ along the closed point I get $\text{Spec } k[\varepsilon_1, \varepsilon_2]/(\varepsilon_1^2, \varepsilon_1 \varepsilon_2, \varepsilon_2^2)$ which is what I would expect. Can you reproduce the details of the calculation?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: $k[x,y]/(x,y)^2$ is what I mean by $k[\varepsilon_1, \varepsilon_2]$.  This notation is used for instance in https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0B28 thought maybe it's not standard everywhere.

Comment: Oh. I thought you meant $k[\varepsilon_1, \varepsilon_2]/(\varepsilon_1^2, \varepsilon_2^2)$ and were confused by this result. I don't see anything confusing about the other result: it's just what you get when you "truncate" $k[x, y]/(xy)$ to first order.